# SharePoint 2010 Upgrade to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I tried to upgrade SharePoint Foundation 2010 Fresh web application to SharePoint 2013.
I found out that upgrade will stuck at some point.

[image]

I can only see one error in error log.

[image]

But i already installed report server in SharePoint 2013 environment.

[image]

More info:

SharePoint 2010 Build version
[image]

SharePoint 2013 Build version
[image]

Even though I installed Report server after run the 'Test-SPContentDatabase' command throws following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if this is an issue in your 2010 environment. In central admin if you go to Review Problems and Solutions you can check to see if there are any "Missing server side dependencies". I tend to try and remove this in a non-production environment first, before moving it to 2013 just to be sure it doesn't cause any issues in prod. MissingFeatures are always a nuisance. This [feature admin tool](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=featureadmin)  has worked for me in the past.

also look at [this releases.](https://github.com/SharePointPog/FeatureAdmin/releases)